# iOS push notification in delayed Network

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip

iOS push notification in delayed Network

We are developing iOS VOIP app it supposed work in 5/6 second delayed network in running background, Our observation is in 4 second delayed network any push notification does not arrive from Apples APNS server to our VoIP app as a result incoming call missed when it goes suspended.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You need to use third party framework :- https://www.pushwoosh.com/

Comment: Give a try to socket programming, as suggested you can not depends on APNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely on push notification for such feature, push notification may never arrive.

if you want to use third party app i will suggest you to use
Sinch :https://www.sinch.com/downloads/